# Is it possible to group participants in PlantUML?

Tags: plantuml

I want to have a box around a couple of participants showing that they are part of an entity. How can you do this in PlantUML?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can "box" participants as shown on plantuml site (extract below)

```
@startuml

box "Internal Service" #LightBlue
participant Bob
participant Alice
end box
participant Other

Bob -> Alice : hello
Alice -> Other : hello

@enduml
```

This produces:
[image]