# How to have a box include a group in PlantUML?

Tags: markdown, plantuml

I am using PlantUML in Markdown for some sequence diagrams, and I would like to be able to group participants accordingly.

In my sequence diagrams, I make use of the `alt` grouping keyword to distinguish between different outcomes. However, when I use the `box` command to group participants, the box doesn't include the `alt` group inside its shading.

In the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667436/is-it-possible-to-group-participants-in-plantuml), the OP asks how to group participants in PlantUML. My question is different because I would like to find out how to get the box coloring to include the test-case, instead of wrapping around it.

**Existing participants grouping effect**

```
@startuml

box "Internal Service" #LightBlue
participant Bob
participant Alice
end box
participant Other

Bob -> Alice : hello
Alice -> Other : hello

@enduml
```

which yields [image]

Original source code credit for this example comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667436/is-it-possible-to-group-participants-in-plantuml), and credit goes to [Jean-Marc Volle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6092788/jean-marc-volle)

**My problem**

I have attached a minimal reproducible example below. Notice how the grey shading, which indicates a group, does not shade through the `alt` test-cases? I would like to know how I can have the shading be included.

```
@startuml
actor pm 
box "app"
participant A
participant B
end box
participant C
participant D

A --> B: message 
alt Test A
A --> B: something
else Test B
B --> C: something else
end group
@enduml
```

which yields
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of PlantUML are you using?

When I put your code into PlantUML.com, I get this result:

[image]